# drop down list upon key entry

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am interested in creating a drop down list upon key entry from a sql database. There are many examples given here for a drop down list however I am not just interested in that, I want the user input to initiate the drop down and it narrows down to the result with each additional entries. It is similar to facebook search and youtube search and some other popular websites. This is very efficient for a database with a large number data within a list.

eg. The user wants to enter Dog for animal name, and in my sql list for animals beginning wih "d" I have dog, dolphin, donkey, deer,...etc.
Now when the User enters "d", dog, dolphin, donkey, deer,...etc would come up, and when they enter "o", (by now they would have "do") the list would just change to just dog, donkey, dolphin.

Is there a code for this? and could I be directed to where I can get this information?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: make an ajax call to the php file with the key enter in the textbox for search and select from database where animal name like your keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an ajax call with your keyword.
you can try this if it will help . ajax base search [here](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful resource

Answer (score 1):

You can do that uing sql query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM AnimalsTable
WHERE AnimalsTable.AnimalName like 'searchTextCriteria%'
```

where **AnimalsTable** i your table name, 
**AnimalName** is your column name,
**searchTextCriteria** is your inputed text

You can handle your textbox's keydown event and every time execute this query